# How do I configure Caliburn for an open generic viewmodel with one view

Tags: c#, wpf, generics, caliburn.micro, caliburn

I found several [questions](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/discussions/231034) on codeplex, even a solved [issue](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/workitem/78) report on this same question but still I'm unable to get it to work.

I have a generic viewmodel that looks like this:

```
public class DialogViewModel<TRespone>
{
     public DialogViewModel(DialogBoxModel<TRespone> dialog)
     {
         this.Dialog = dialog;
     }

     public DialogBoxModel<TRespone> Dialog {get;set;}

     //...
}
```

I want to show the same view every time for every closed generic type of the viewmodel requested. My view looks like:

```
<Window x:Class="Test.WPF.Dialogs.DialogBox.DialogView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" >
    <Grid>
       <!--....-->
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

NOTE: My view and viewmodel is in the exact same namespace!

I tried to show my viewmodel using the `WindowManager.ShowDialog()` method with different approaches, like this:

```
public TResponse ShowDialog<TResponse>(DialogBoxModel<TResponse> dialogModel)
{
    var vm = new DialogViewModel<TResponse>(dialogModel);

    // tried first, without any context
    var result = this.windowManager.ShowDialog(vm);

    // tried second: using the fullname of the generic type 
    var genericTypeName =  typeof(TResponse).FullName;
    result = this.windowManager.ShowDialog(vm,genericTypeName);

    // tried third: using the name of the generic type (ToFriendlyName is 
    // an extension method which extracts only the name and leaves the namespace
    // etc. for what it is
    genericTypeName = typeof(TResponse).ToFriendlyName();
    result = this.windowManager.ShowDialog(vm, genericTypeName);
}
```

Unfortunately which each approach I got the same error, namely a TextBlock with the text: `Cannot find view for {0}.` in a otherwise empty window.

As the [issue](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/workitem/78) seems to be solved I think it should be possible so what am I missing here? I must be doing something really wrong...?

**UPDATE**

It seems like I solved it, but the scary part is: I did not change anything, I just removed Caliburn alltogether and let NuGet install it again. My first try (without context) does the trick.

Anyway comment on this...?